# How to avoid NoSuchElementException in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm making a python music player, which plays music through the headless chrome browser using Youtube Music. However, when I fill in the input form for the song name, I would sometimes get a noSuchElementException. It happens less often than not, and when it doesn't happen the code runs smoothly without any problems.

Here is my the section of my code:

```
def searchMusic():
    ask = input("What song would you like to listen to?: ")
    print("- - - - - - - - ")
    if ask != " ":
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        search_initiate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="icon"]')
        search_initiate.click()
        search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(IF.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
        '/html/body/ytmusic-app/ytmusic-app-layout/ytmusic-nav-bar/div[2]/ytmusic-search-box/div/div[1]/input')))
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        search_bar.send_keys(ask)
        search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        heading1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]/ytmusic-responsive-list-item-renderer')
        for i in range(4):
            print(heading1[i].text)
            print("- - - - - - -")
```

And here is the exception:

```
 File "/Users/kevinhadinata/Desktop/Python/headless.py", line 92, in <module>
    searchMusic()
  File "/Users/kevinhadinata/Desktop/Python/headless.py", line 56, in searchMusic
    search_initiate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="icon"]')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="icon"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: URL of Youtube Music?

Comment: @DebanjanB it is already set, driver.get('https://music.youtube.com/')

Answer (score 1):

simply check if element exist:

```
check = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="icon"]')
if len(check) > 0:
    go further
else:
    no data
```

Comment: I tried that, but if I couldn't select the search bar, wouldn't the whole program be practically useless? @Zaraki Kenpachi

Comment: @Kevin H then you need to search why this element is not visible. This is not an unified case. Each web page has different methods do display some elements.

Comment: yeah, I'm kinda stumped on finding the cause for this right now, but I figured some suggestions for a possible cause would help.

Comment: @Kevin H without minimal reproducible example of code the help is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use proper method to wait element so you can ignore nosuchelement issue,If you write and keep wait method in your program you can use that method anywhere and anytime in your programme 

------------------------------------------------------

     private static WebElement waitForElement(By locator, int timeout)
    {
        WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return element;
    }
    ------------------------------------------------------

// for example if you want wait an element with id use below code 
waitForElement(By.id(""),20);
20 is milliseconds
```

Comment: I tried that, and now it is giving me a TimeoutException

Comment: are you referring to the error message? because i have already included the code in my post.